# Resizing UITextView to fit content in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

This is my second view called detail view and I am bringing over text from the first view into the detail view.  Some of the text is larger than others, so I am trying to make it to where my textview changes automatically to adapt to the amount of text needed.  I am still new to Swift so any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var symptomsTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var stepsTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var emergencyLabel: UILabel!
var medicalObject : MedicalInfo? = nil
var emergencyText = ""
var symptomsText = ""
var stepsText = ""


//Function to show text in labels and text views
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Adding text to the labels and text views
    emergencyLabel.text = emergencyText
    symptomsTextView.text = symptomsText
    stepsTextView.text = stepsText
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Say, for example, that you wanted stepsTextLabel to resize to fit the content size. In order to do so, you would write `stepsTextLabel.sizeToFit()` and it would resize it for you.

Comment: I just tried that in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and it didn't work.